# Distinct SQL that will return true if in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm drawing a blank on the best way write this sql,
For simplicity sake I'm Only interested in one column.
Table A Column = [Supplier]. 
Table B Column = [AuthorizedSuppliers]

Table A contains many rows with the same value in the [Supplier].

```
Table A
------------------------------
ID |Supplier      | Company  |
---|--------------|----------|
1  | Warehouse 1  | Company 1|
2  | Warehouse 1  | Company 2|
3  | Warehouse 1  | Company 3|
4  | Warehouse 2  | Company 4|
5  | Warehouse 2  | Company 5|
6  | Warehouse 3  | Company 6|
7  | Warehouse 3  | Company 7|
8  | Warehouse 3  | Company 8|
```

Table B contains a single Supplier from Table A [Supplier] row.

```
Table B
------------------------------
ID |AuthorizedSupplier       |
---|-------------------------|
1  | Warehouse 1             | 
2  | Warehouse 2             |
```

I need to return the DISTINCT values of [Supplier] and [AuthorizedSupplier] with a additional column let's call it [Authorized] that is marked as true for those values that were in Table B

So the result set of the above sample should look like this

```
Result Set
------------------------------
Supplier    |Authorized      |
------------|----------------|
Warehouse 1 | True           |
Warehouse 2 | True           |
Warehouse 3 | False          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Distinct` and  `Left Outer Join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Supplier, Authorized = CASE WHEN B.AuthorizedSupplier IS NULL
                                       THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B
  ON A.Supplier = B.AuthorizedSupplier
```

[**SQL-Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80d63/6/0)

Comment: Thanks. That is a lot less complicated than I expected. I feel like an idiot now but It's been over a year since I really had my hand in SQL. Quite rusty.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Supplier
     , CASE WHEN B.AuthorizedSupplier IS NULL
          THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END  AS Authorized
 FROM (Select Distinct Supplier
         FROM TableA)          A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct A.Supplier, (Case When B.Id IS NULL Then 0 else 1 end) Authorized
from TableA A
    Left Outer Join TableB  B ON A.Supplier = B.AuthorizedSupplier
```